# Viewing & testing plain HTML & CSS that is under development on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Pretty straightforward, front-end development question.  In the past, when our front end contractor has developed the html & css for our non-mobile web projects, he creates a html/css mockup page(s), and while developing, just open the file(s) directly in his browser, e.g. file:///Users/me/code/proj/file.html .  Once the mockup files looks good, he passes them off to us, the backend developers, and we adapt them to work with real data and run on our platform.

Now, we're developing a mobile-specific site, and we're trying to adapt our development process.  I'd like for him to be able to still develop simple html/css mockup files, but he's unsure how to test them as he's developing.  Having him run the full web app development platform that our core developers use is not a straight-forward option.

So, with mobile (android & ios, atm), what's the simplest way to continually be able to view simple html/css that is under development on an actual device or emulator? I don't see a way to open a file system file in iOS simulator.  Should I have him run a simple webserver? (If so, which?) What do you front-end guys typically do to effectively develop for mobile?

Comment: I'd look into [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/). That said, this is a shopping/poll question. Obviously you know what your options are, try them and see which one fits best.

Comment: Is it an app that you're developing or a mobile website built using html/css? For an app the designer could just pass you JPGs of the designs couldn't they as the html/css would be irrelevant? Unless it's an HTML5 app you're making I guess.

Comment: You could use the firefox pulgin "Web Developer 1.2.2" there you can add resizing presets and simply switch to them using the toolbar.

Comment: @millimoose As a front-end noob, i don't know what my options are although i can guess at a few. For example, never heard of mongoose.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Use http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html, then  have everyone work out of the same assets directory (img,css,js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a technical writer, not a developer. We recently started creating help for mobile devices. Initial tests are done like this:

- We have a local Apache Tomcat installation (we use Windows, but Tomcat also runs on the Mac).
- We create a subfolder in the Tomcat web directory. This is where our help files go.
- When we call myhost:8080/myfolder or something like this, the index.html page of our output is displayed.
- Then we do a rough check of how the output would look like on mobile devices using http://www.responsinator.com/.

Comment: Holy cow. Responsinator is awesome! Thanks for pointing that out!